# Detecting unused functions at build time in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to get the GHC to warn me whenever I write a new function and forget to use it anywhere. I've added the following function in my Main.hs:

```
unused :: () -> ()
unused _ = ()
```

and of course not used it.

I have the following in my *.cabal file:

```
 ghc-options: 
    -W
    -Wall
    -Werror
    -Wcompat
    -Wincomplete-uni-patterns
    -Wincomplete-record-updates
    -Wredundant-constraints
    -Wpartial-fields
    -Wunused-binds
```

I've specifically added -Wunused-binds to try to force the compiler to fail on this but it does not report any warning about an unused function.

Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

Just to give a bigger picture, here is the beggining of the main file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds                  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies               #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

module Main where

import           Apecs
import           Linear                         ( V2(..) )
import           Control.Monad
import           Control.Monad.IO.Class
import           Control.Monad.Catch
import qualified System.Terminal               as T
import           System.Terminal.Internal
import qualified Data.Map                      as M
import           System.Random
```

Comment: If you export a function from a module, it is counted as being used. Perhaps that is what’s happening here?

Comment: @bradrn If I'm doing it, then not on purpose. I've added the beginning of the main file, is it somehow exported automatically?

Comment: @kajman Yes. Everything in a module is exported unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Thanks, I exported only the main function and now it works as expected.

Comment: You can also use `weeder` to find dead code hiding in your project (e.g. exported in a module but never used elsewhere in the project)

Answer (score 2):

Exporting only main function from module fixed the issue:

```
module Main(main) where
```

**EDIT**

Just for reference, this flag is already contained in -Wall so it would be enough to have this in cabal to catch it:

```
  ghc-options: 
    -Wall
    -Werror
```